How to make component draggable and connected in Javafx
I am developing a javafx application for network topology. I have one pane where I drag the components from the left pane to the centre pane. Now the problem is sometimes if the pane is cluttered with many components then I want to re-arrange the components. Also, I want to link the components.
I have written below code. The problem I am facing is both the drag and connecting are listening to mouse event. So if drag a component, it is drawing line, if I draw a line, it is dragging the component. I am not sure how to separate those 2.
Code for drag component:
    @FXML
void handleDragRequest(MouseEvent event) {
    logger.info("Container is re-positioned");
    paneId.getChildren().forEach(this::makeDraggable);
}
     
    private void makeDraggable(Node node) {
    node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        startX = e.getSceneX() - node.getTranslateX();
        startY = e.getSceneY() - node.getTranslateY();
    });
    node.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
        node.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX() - startX);
        node.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY() - startY);
    });
}

    @FXML
void joinByLineEnd(MouseEvent event) {
    logger.info("Calculating cordinates for line - End");
    lineEndX = event.getX();
    lineEndY = event.getY();
    Line line = new Line(lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY);
    paneId.getChildren().addAll(line);
}

@FXML
void joinByLineStart(MouseEvent event) {
    logger.info("Calculating cordinates for line - Start");
    lineStartX = event.getX();
    lineStartY = event.getY();
}

FXML:
<Pane fx:id="paneId" 
    layoutX="94.0" 
    onDragDetected="#handleDragRequest" 
    onMousePressed="#joinByLineStart" 
    onMouseReleased="#joinByLineEnd" 
    prefHeight="700.0" 
    prefWidth="868.0" 
/>



Consider using a modified gesture (e.g. Shift+ mouse or Shortcut + mouse) for one of the actions. You need to have some way of distinguishing the user's intentions.

See if this can work for you, or maybe you can learn from it.

This seems a bit different, but perhaps this example of dragging polygon points may help.

@James_D. Thank you. will try the solution as mentioned.

@jewelsea. will  check and try.

@James_D i tried your suggestion.. i tried with "onkeypressed" event. But I guess this event will be triggered with any key being pressed. How to make sure or limit it to "shift" key being pressed? Any idea?

Just use a mouse handler and an appropriate method call (for example) on the mouse event.
